# Servlet Filter modify path to files

Tags: web-applications, servlets, servlet-filters

Could you help me with implementation Filter which will modify all request to files /DIR/* into /NEW_DOMAIN/NEW_CONTEXT_PATH/DIR/*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Map the filter to `/DIR/*`
2. Use

   ```
   response.sendRedirect(NEW_DOMAIN + "/" + NEW_CONTEXT + request.getPathInfo())
   ```

   (see [`getPathInfo()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getPathInfo%28%29)). Note that if it's possible to have a query-string (`?foo=bar`), you'd have to append it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Probably could but are you sure that is what you want? You could also use mod_rewrite with your reverse proxy (example for Apache and mod_rewrite):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule   ^/DIR/(.*)$  /NEW_DOMAIN/NEW_CONTEXT_PATH/DIR/$1  [R]
```